# intersecting polygons and polylines, using google maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a polygon and polyline created dynamically. Now I need to check whether they both intersect each other or not.

How do I achieve this? Googling hasn't provided any satisfactory results.

Thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over each segment of the first polygon/polyline and check if it intersects each segment of the second polygon/polyline. If one intersects, there the two geometries intersect.

If you don't need to take into account geodesic lines, you can take a look at the suggested implementations here: [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect) (there is also a Javascript implementation that may suit your needs: https://github.com/pgkelley4/line-segments-intersect/blob/master/js/line-segments-intersect.js)

Comment: This was the best answer ever! I was looking for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Turf.js it provides you very simple `lineIntersect` method you pass it coordinates1, coordinates2 and it gives you the array of exact intersections.
[Turf.js lineIntersect documentation](http://turfjs.org/docs/#lineIntersect)