# how can i find intersecting point of two routes in google maps api java android?

Tags: android, google-maps

As the title states I want to know how can I find Intersecting point of two different routes in google maps API.

please view this image for better visualisation:

[image: Intersection]

Answer (score 1):

You can use, for example, [`PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(LatLng point, java.util.List<LatLng> polyline, boolean geodesic, double tolerance)`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-double-) from [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/?hl=en). In this case you need to iterate over each point of the "red" polyline and check (with `isLocationOnPath()`) if it intersects (lays on) each segment of the "blue" polyline. Something like that:

```
for (LatLng point : redPolyline.getPoints()) {
    if (PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(point, bluePolyline.getPoints(), true, 50)) {
        // now "point" - is your target point
        pointWhatYouWantToGet = point;
        ...
    }
}
```

where `50` - is tolerance (in meters).

If you need polylines segments intersection, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38431572/6950238) answer of [antonio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4558709/antonio).

Comment: thank you for the answer also If you know what is minimum tolerance i can give for better precision please let me know.

Comment: @adilraza Tolerance depends of your tasks. 20..70m is enough typically.